# How to achieve at-least-once delivery guarantee with RabbitMQ and Spring AMQP without using transactions?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

This document https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html says it is possible to achieve at-least-once guarantee with RabbitMQ without using transactions. The problem with transactions is that they are slow, so the throughput drops drastically (see sections Publisher Confirms in https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html). The option is to use Consumer Acknowledgements and Publisher Confirms.

On the other hand, Spring AMQP is able to handle Consumer Acknowledgements automatically using this configuration:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.acknowledgeMode=AUTO
```

For Publisher Confirms this is the configuration:

```
spring.rabbitmq.publisherConfirms=true
```

My doubt is whether these two properties are enough to guarantee at-least-once delivery or if I need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a confirm callback to the rabbit template (either a custom one or the one configured by boot) to get the confirmations. You can add correlation data to the message sends so that you can correlate the confirm with the send.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#template-confirms).

> For Publisher Confirms (aka Publisher Acknowledgements), the template requires a CachingConnectionFactory that has its publisherConfirms property set to true. Confirms are sent to to the client by it registering a RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback by calling setConfirmCallback(ConfirmCallback callback). The callback must implement this method:
>
> `void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause);`
>
> The CorrelationData is an object supplied by the client when sending the original message. The ack is true for an ack and false for a nack. For nack s, the cause may contain a reason for the nack, if it is available when the nack is generated. An example is when sending a message to a non-existent exchange. In that case the broker closes the channel; the reason for the closure is included in the cause. cause was added in version 1.4.
>
> Only one ConfirmCallback is supported by a RabbitTemplate.